# High disk usage with windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, performance

I have a problem that whenever I start playing Call of Duty Advanced Warfare on my PC, it gets really laggy.  When I open the task manager, I find that the disk usage is at a 100%, mainly used by the system "ntoskrnl".  This only happens with AW.  As soon as I exit the game, the disk usage drops down to 1-2%

I don't have an antivirus.  I disabled super fetch and Windows search services and I had no luck.  I defragmented my disk and performed a disk check with no problems.  I played BF4, BF3, Crysis 3, and Farcry 3, all on high settings, with no problems.

edit:
xperf trace :http://www.2shared.com/file/t6QK-S-o/xperf_trace.html

xperf trace game running :2shared.com/file/wNUcgn2q/xerf_trace.html

laptop specs: hp envy m6-1105dx amd a10 4600m 8gb ram 5400rpm hdd

a quick question :i found out that the vram is only 512mb is there a way to increase the vram sense i have shared ram not a dedicated one for the gpu

Comment: 1. Get an antivirus. 2. re-enable prefetch.

Comment: I bet it's the high quality textures of CoD:AW that's causing the high disk usage. Try reducing the texture quality and see whether performance improves. Also, a little info about your computer would be nice. You can't expect a game like CoD:AW to work well on an entry-level or even mid-range gaming system without a bit of tweaking.

Comment: You might have insufficient VRAM so the game needs to access your hard disk frequently to alternate between the textures. If you are interested in figuring out the exact issue then try following **[these instructions](http://superuser.com/a/849112/259665)**

Comment: follow this and upload the xperf trace: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60

Comment: thnx for the replies and sorry for not giving enough info  i play it on a laptop hp envy m6 1105dx amd a10 4600m with 8 gb of ram       i think you both are right but i just found it weird that the cpu is at 65% and the disk at 100% (mainly the system not the game)

Comment: a quick question :i found out that the vram is only 512mb is there a way to increase the vram sense i have  shared ram not a dedicated one for the gpu?

Comment: xperf trace :http://www.2shared.com/file/t6QK-S-o/xperf_trace.html

Answer (score 3):

i think i solved the problem

it seems the problem was in the virtual memory that was set to 1200mb i changed it to 4472mb min and 8944mb max   rebooted and the game is smooth now disk usage still spikes high sometimes but doesnt seem to affect the performance

any way thnxx for the replies

Comment: in the trace there is no access to the pagefile. Next time you have to capture the trace when you run into this issue and not when the system is fine

Comment: sorry i didn't know that    but as i said setting the virtual memory to 4472mb instead of 1200mb helped alot i rarely get the same high disk usage as i used to but here it is and thnxx for the reply http://www.2shared.com/file/wNUcgn2q/xerf_trace.html

Comment: run this command to also capture Memory data: http://pastebin.com/ZquQj02W. And please run it a bit longer

Comment: @magicandre1981
i hope i got it right this time here it is

http://www.2shared.com/file/AwULj8Ub/xperf.html

Comment: ok, your Memory is sometimes over 6GB of your 7.6GB. So Windows wants to page out some data. So increasing the pagefile improves your situation.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thnx a million dude ,    
so 4 gb of pagefile is still not enough! i will change it to 8gb and see what happens thnx again

Comment: you should think of upgrading the RAM to at least 12GB. Maybe you can get it as a Christmas present from someone.

Comment: hahaha yeah i should lay the leg work and let people know :p